# What does “turn as I would” mean in “The circular rift vanished; nor could I get a glimpse of it afterwards, turn as I would” mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

There is the following passage in a famous novel of Edgar Allan Poe, “The Golden Bug” written in 1843.

> “Having carefully taken the bearing of the tree, I turned homewards.
>   The instant that I left ‘the devil’s seat,’ however the circular rift
>   vanished: nor could I get a glimpse of it afterwards, **turn as I
>   would.”**

How should I interpret the phrase, “turn as I would.”? Is this usage of 'as' very common? Does it mean '(though) Legrand, the teller looked back again and again the bearing of the circular rift where a death's-head is placed'?

Comment: It means that no matter what direction he turned, he could not see it.

Comment: Yep, "XXX as I would" means doing XXX any way I could think of.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[***As***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/as), as a conjunction, can mean "**even though**" with following examples:

> ‘Try as she might, she can't keep her troubled family from
>   fragmenting.’
>
> ‘But, good as he is, he was not the only reason to enjoy the film.’
>
> ‘Unless you are of a particularly curious bent, you would not even
>   wish to sit down and eat with these people - dazzlingly clever as they
>   undoubtedly are.’

[Oxford Online Dictionary]

You can notice that "adjectives" and "verbs" are positioned before "as".

In your context, it means:

> "Even though I would turn (to get a glimpse of it)."